# Most "vanila" linux distrib

Tags: linux

Tell me please the distribution with the most clear from patches kernel. I wanna try myself in kernel-module writing, and i suppose that a heavily-patched kernel can interfere me. thanks

Comment: How about you just build your own? It's not rocket-science and ultra-vanilla … ;) That said, I'm running self-built vanilla kernel in all of my gentoo systems.

Comment: Since the definition of "most vanilla" distribution is very subjective, it is difficult to provide an objective answer to this question.

Comment: On Debian and related (Ubuntu) systems, building the kernel from vanilla http://kernel.org/ sources is quite easy, using `make-kpkg --initrd` utility; and the kernels run flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most vanilla distribution that I know of is Slackware.

Comment: @NerdP: See here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-vanilla-kernel-philosophy-613913/

Comment: @NerdP: The Slackware website: http://www.slackware.com/